# Autoresize UIScrollView To Fit UILabel Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have been searching for quite a while now, and every answer I find doesn't seem to work. I have a view, code below, that holds a bunch of text that is pulled from a YouTube video description from another view. Obviously ever video's descriptions are of different length, which is what poses the problem. I want to make it that the scrollview only scrolls down to about 10 pixels after the last text line of the label.

In this code, I don't have it doing that, I have it at a fixed size.

Can ANYONE help? I have been searching for days now, and I can seem to find a proper solution.

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

//int a = VideoDescription.length;
//NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", a]);

if(VideoDescription.length < 310)
{
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n_______________________________________________"];
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n\nFor the best viewing experience, please use WiFi."];
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n\nWant an app like this for your YouTube Channel? Go to www.apps4tubers.com to find out how you can get one!"];
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n\nDon't forget to rate this app! Love it? Hate it? Regardless we love to hear your comments and suggestions!"];
}
else if(VideoDescription.length < 380)
{
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n_______________________________________________"];
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n\nFor the best viewing experience, please use WiFi."];
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n\nWant an app like this for your YouTube Channel? Go to www.apps4tubers.com to find out how you can get one!"];
}
else if(VideoDescription.length > 379 && VideoDescription.length < 410)
{
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n_______________________________________________"];
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n\nWant an app like this for your YouTube Channel? Go to www.apps4tubers.com to find out how you can get one!"];
}
else
{
    VideoDescription = [VideoDescription stringByAppendingString:@"\n\nFor the best viewing experience, please use WiFi."];
}

CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
TheView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 650);
[TheView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
[TheView setPagingEnabled:NO];
TheView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
TheView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
TheView.bounces = NO;
[self.view addSubview:TheView];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

Background = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(00, 25, 1000, 1600)];
Background.center = CGPointMake(00, 00);
Background.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"111625"];
[TheView addSubview: Background];

VideoDecrip = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(00, 25, 320, 400)];
VideoDecrip.center = CGPointMake(160.5, 400);
VideoDecrip.text = VideoDescription;
VideoDecrip.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Cochin-Bold" size: 13.5];
VideoDecrip.textColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"D1E751"];
VideoDecrip.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.35];
VideoDecrip.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
VideoDecrip.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
VideoDecrip.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
VideoDecrip.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
VideoDecrip.textAlignment = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
VideoDecrip.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
VideoDecrip.numberOfLines = 0;
[VideoDecrip sizeToFit];
[TheView addSubview: VideoDecrip];

NSLog(@"%i", VideoDecrip.text.length);

VideoTitleBorder = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(00, 25, 320.5, 30)];
VideoTitleBorder.center = CGPointMake(160, 182.5);
VideoTitleBorder.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
VideoTitleBorder.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"0B486B"];
VideoTitleBorder.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
VideoTitleBorder.layer.borderWidth = .4;
[TheView addSubview: VideoTitleBorder];

VideoTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(00, 25, 320, 26)];
VideoTitle.text = VidTitle;
if([VideoTitle.text length] < 20)
{
    VideoTitle.center = CGPointMake(160, 182.5);
}
else if([VideoTitle.text length] < 30)
{
    VideoTitle.center = CGPointMake(160, 182);
}
else
{
    VideoTitle.center = CGPointMake(160, 179);
}
VideoTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"ArialRoundedMTBold" size: 25];
VideoTitle.textColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"BEF202"];
VideoTitle.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
VideoTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
VideoTitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
VideoTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
VideoTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[TheView addSubview: VideoTitle];

VideoTitleBorder2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(00, 25, 160, 500)];
VideoTitleBorder2.center = CGPointMake(400, 125);
VideoTitleBorder2.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
VideoTitleBorder2.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"0B486B"];
VideoTitleBorder2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
VideoTitleBorder2.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
[self.view addSubview: VideoTitleBorder2];
```

Comment: If you can generate HTML for the description you can use DTCoreText to render it. https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

Comment: This may sound noobish, but I have never heard of UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can use the `NSString` method `-sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` to determine how tall the string will render in a container with the given width and line break mode.  You can use that to size your `UILabel` and to set the scrollview's contentsize appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sizeToFit`on the label, then setting the scrollView's `contentSize`:

```
[label sizeToFit];  
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(label.frame) + 10)];
```

Using `sizeToFit` is really nice, just make sure your label is already the right width before you call it.